# does calling stringByAppendingPathComponent() multiple times overrides the old file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I created a function called dataFilePath(). This method creates a file data.plist in Documents directory and returns it's path. I'm wondering..if data.plist allready exists in Documents directory (for example I called this function the second time) does this methods deletes the old data.plist and creates a new one, or does it just return a path of the previously created data.plist file?

```
func dataFilePath() -> String{
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = path[0] as NSString
        return documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByAppendingPathComponent()` just builds a *string*. It does not
make any access to the file system and in particular does not verify if a file with that name exists, or create a file with that name.

To check if a file with a given path exists, use the `NSFileManager()`
methods, such as `fileExistsAtPath()`.

Comment: ou, my bad. So it just gets path of the file data.plist if that file is in the Document directory.

Comment: @krompir2: It just creates a path ".../Documents/data.plist", no matter if that file exists or not. It does not even check if the Documents directory exists.